# Cannot Scan QR Stylized QR Code using ZBar & ZXing Libs

Tags: qr-code

Im having trouble in reading our stylized QR Codes. By the way, the QR Codes are stylized using Adobe Photoshop.

https://scontent-lax3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xft1/v/t34.0-12/11992513_901280573259284_1879944565_n.jpg?oh=f225b84841ed4b9c820aed9c6ccf2679&oe=55EECDB5

I have followed the instructions thoroughly

1. Added dependency on build.gradle

   ```
   compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.2'
   ```
2. Modify the MainActivity

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ZBarScannerView.ResultHandler {

   private ZBarScannerView mScannerView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       mScannerView = new ZBarScannerView(this);
       mScannerView.setAutoFocus(true);
       mScannerView.setFlash(true);
       List<BarcodeFormat> formats = new ArrayList<BarcodeFormat>();
       formats.add(BarcodeFormat.QRCODE);
       mScannerView.setFormats(formats);

       mScannerView.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLACK));
       mScannerView.setBackgroundTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
       setContentView(mScannerView);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
       mScannerView.startCamera();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       mScannerView.stopCamera();
   }



   @Override
   public void handleResult(Result result) {
       Log.d("---------------------", result.getContents()); // Prints scan results
       Log.d("---------------------", result.getBarcodeFormat().getName());
       Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
   ```

   }
3. And upon running the Regular QR Code is read perfectly but our custom QR can't.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Your QR scans okay for me using Quick Mark. Light on dark QR codes can't be scanned by some scanners, eg, red on white would be better than white on red. I hope this helps!~